# difference between re._compile in python 2.6 vs 2.7

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a a regex : `([\w\s()-]+):[\s+\B]?([\d,.]+)`

to catch string in format similar to

```
ignore-packets(vlan)  : 49,971
```

when I run it with python 2.7 it works as expected 
but when i run it using

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, May  1 2012, 13:52:17)
```

I get the following error:

```
    m = re.findall(r'([\w\s\(\)-]+):[\s+\B]?([\d,\.]+)', l)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: internal: unsupported set operator
```

using the [reference](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) I've added '\' before special chars (().) but problem still occur

what am I missing here ?

Comment: Replace `[\s+\B]?` with `\s*`.

Comment: What's `[\s+\B]?`? I don't think that does what you think it does.

Comment: The reason it fails is that the `\B`, a zero-width assertion, is used in a character class (a consuming pattern). This is treated as a human error.